# git pull master without overwriting my files on the local branch

Tags: git

Some files that were in the master branch were deleted by another dev, in my local branch I had already committed the changes and now I want to pull from the master and keep my files in the local branch, how to do that?

Comment: you can use `git fetch` for the first step

Comment: I already ran git fetch, when I run the ```git pull origin master``` command, it conflicts with my local branch because some files that were in master were deleted but exist in my local branch, but I want to keep the files in my local branch, how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If another user has deleted a file and moved it to the remote branch, this operation cannot be undone and you cannot ignore it!

But you can move your local master to a new local branch with `git checkout -b "localMasterBackup"`. **Make a commit!** and then do the `git pull origin master` and you can afterwards merge the localMasterBackup into the current master.

Comment: The OP would have to rewind your local `master` to before his commits for this to work, wouldn't (s)he?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to deal with the merge conflict(s) whichever path you choose for this situation (delete & change).

`git pull (--rebase)` + resolving conflicts is entirely normal here.

---

If you have multiple people working on a long-lived branch you may want to switch to the industry standard of protected branches + pull requests.